# Dark Fantasy Novel Identification

Tags: story-identification, novel, dragons

I'm trying to identify a novel I read back in the 90s.  I'm going to list a bunch of random facts that I remember in the hope that someone will recognize it.  I'm not sure of the names I list below, so please take the names with a grain of salt.

- The novel centered around and was told from the perspective of a warlord.  He had been resurrected(?) along with 10 or so others to lead armies and conquer.  He could use magic and change his appearance.
- I remember that the first use of his magic was to conjure a heavy fur cape after he is resurrected.
- He and the others each fill a goblet with blood and pass it around to learn about each other.
- He carries a marble in the crook of his elbow that contains the soul of a giant/ogre/troll(something)  that he captured and uses to spy.
- He ran the [giant's] people off a cliff and captured the leaders soul when the leader stabbed himself in the neck rather than jump.
- The more magic that he uses the more he transforms into a dragon.  I think two of the other characters are Saffa Firehair and Bors.
- Bors started transforming into a dragon at some point and went crazy for a couple of years while he gathered the magic to complete the dragon.
- There was some super powerful character, the one who resurrected and controlled the twelve, who was imprisoned in a block of obsidian.
- The twelve revolted and tried to kill him, but were unable to and so imprisoned him instead.

These are most of the facts that I can remember.  Thank you to anyone that can help me to identify the book, or at least clarify/add to the details I can't remember clearly.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "to lead armies and concur"? Does that mean to act with those 10 others?

Comment: Sorry, that was an auto-correct typo I overlooked.  I meant conquer.  As far as the group,  they seem to be adversarial allies.  The work together at times, but the have also attacked and fought with each other.

Comment: Aeren Firehair = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hero_and_the_Crown

Comment: I've read that book, and enjoyed it, but that's not the one I'm thinking of.  Thanks for the suggestion though.